# On convex subgroups of totally ordered groups.

Tags: group-theory, set-theory, ordered-groups

I am trying to find an example of a totally ordered abelian group $(\Gamma,+)$ such that the set of its convex subgroups is $\textbf{not}$ totally ordered.

I think there should be such an example, but something tells me it is not so trivial. Any help or reference would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It **is** totally ordered.

Indeed, let $A,B$ be convex subgroups, and suppose $b\in B-A$, and $a\in A-B$. Up to invert, we can suppose $a,b\ge 0$. Up to switch, we can suppose $a\le b$. So $0\le a\le b$. By convexity, $a\in B$, contradiction.

Note that I used very little of the axioms: I only need a set $G$ with a total order and a basepoint $0$, and an involution $i$ exchanging $G_{\ge 0}$ and $G_{\le 0}$: then the set of $i$-invariant convex subsets is totally ordered.

Comment: +1. You didn't use and didn't need "Abelian".   The lexicographic (dictionary) order on $\Bbb R^2$ with group operation $(x,y)*(x',y')=(x+x',y+y'e^x)$ is an example of a non-Abelian fully-ordered group.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes. For non-abelian groups, one distinguishes left/right/bi-ordered/orderable groups. (Of course left-orderable is equivalent to right-orderable.) Your example (which I know as 2-dimensional affine group) is actually bi-orderable. The above applies to both left-ordered and right-ordered groups.